# React typescript - Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a stackBlitz demo here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-opucum?file=UserList.tsx,App.tsx

I'm following a simple react tutorial creating a simple app where you enter a name and email and it is displayed below.

The tutorial is in js but I want to do it in ts.

I have a UserForm where you enter the name and email

I'm passing in onUserAdd that is used on the App.tsx to add the data to local state

```
import React, { FormEvent, useState } from 'react';

const UserForm = ({ onUserAdd }: any) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  const handelSubmit = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onUserAdd({ name, email });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handelSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Add User </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default UserForm;
```

I have a UserList that takes in the users and displays them in a list, here I've set `{users}:User` but it says  `Property 'users' does not exist on type 'User'.`

```
import React from 'react'

export interface User{
  name:string
  email: string
}

const UserList = ({users}:User) => {
  return (
    <table>
    {users.map((user:User) => {
      return(
        <tr>
          <td>{user.name}</td>
          <td>{user.email}</td>
        </tr>
      )
    })}
    </table>
  )
}

export default UserList
```

Finally I have App.tsx that, here `[...users, user]` says `Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'never'.` and `users={users}` says `Type '{ users: never[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & User'. Property 'users' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & User'.`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import UserForm from './UserForm';
import UserList, { User } from './UserList';


const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
  const onUserAdd = (user:User) => {
    setUsers([...users, user])
  }
  return (
    <>
      <UserForm onUserAdd={onUserAdd}/>
      <UserList users={users}/>
    </>

  );
}

export default App;
```

I know there is a lot going wrong here but I'm sure it's the types I have messed up.

Can anyone see how to simple fix this

Comment: `{users}:User` -> `{users} : { users: User[] }`

Comment: And `const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([])`

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't set what user is in useState, typescript sets it to never[], meaning an type of empty array.

```
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([])
```

After you set it to User[] (Array of users), you need to fix this type as it expects only one user, but you need an array of users

```
const UserList = ({users}:User[]) => {
//
})
```

You do not need to type this part, it now knows what type it is from the User[]

```
    {users.map((user) => {
    //
    })}
```